# What is the most generic way to write a Lagrangian quadratic in velocities?

Tags: metric-spaces, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, connections, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm trying to generalize the expression for a Lagrangian to a manifold that doesn't posses a metric.

To be more clear, when the configurations space has a metric, we write the lagrangian quadratic in velocities as: $L=g_{ij}u^iu^j$ where $g_{ij}$ is the metric tensor and $u=\dot{q}$ are the velocities. But how can I write a generic Lagrangian quadratic in the velocities where the metric tensor doesn't exist?

My final goal is to show that if we have a quadratic lagrangian and the eulero-lagrange equations coincide with the geodesic equations (for some affine connection that is not metric), then the Ricci curvature tensor is symmetric.

Comment: Any smooth quadratic form $Q: M\to S^2M$ will yield a quadratic Lagrangian $T:TM\to \mathbb{R}$ by $T(v)=Q_p(v,v)$ for $v\in T_pM$. This is the most general form of what can mean by a Lagrangian quadratic in velocities since in any basis $Q_p(v,v)=\sum Q_{ij}v^iv^j$.